# initMap is not a function: Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps-api-3

GoogleMap is not visible in my angular Project (WebStorm IDE) !!

I have tried using callback function !! Still the GoogleMap is not visible !!
[I get this Error in Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNdEH.jpg)

---

index.html

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAANu_sjcxDH04GZHg187EGg6csTeiX-jw&callback=initMap"
         defer></script>
```

MapCtrl.js

```
 .controller('MapCtrl',function ($scope, $window) {

$window.initMap = function () {

    var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 8
    });

  }
```

});

Mymap.html

```
<div id="map" ng-controller="MapCtrl"></div>
```

Comment: it should call like initMap() insted of initMap

Comment: Where should I add the initMap() ? I tired adding in the script tag ! It throws "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 () " in the console

Comment: make sure your google map is out of error

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32090622/how-use-initial-google-map-in-angularjs-controller

Comment: In this link , they have not given initMap() --for the callback function  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem once. I solve it by removing '&callback=initMap' from the end of the src url. In your case;

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAANu_sjcxDH04GZHg187EGg6csTeiX-jw"
     defer></script>
```

instead of

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAANu_sjcxDH04GZHg187EGg6csTeiX-jw&callback=initMap"
     defer></script>
```

Comment: I know it's an old answer but it will throw an error if you remove the callback "Loading the Google Maps JavaScript API without a callback is not supported", it's a required parameter now. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/url-params#required_parameters

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some css styles to your map id, this happens to me so many times.

```
html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#map { height: 100%; }
```

If you need more info read [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial?hl=es-419)

Comment: I tired all the solutions !! Still i get the same Error !!   **initMap--Replaced and Tried initMap () **

Comment: try  this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32090622/how-use-initial-google-map-in-angularjs-controller